# Rectangle surmounted by an isosceles triangle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

A window has the shape of a rectangle surmounted by an isosceles triangle. Determine the dimensions of the window, if its if its perimeter is to be at most $M$ and its area is to be maximized.

I have tried to solve it this way:

Let $y$ and $z$ be the height and width of the rectangle and let $x$ be the side of the isosceles triangle. The area will be maximum when the perimeter will be maximum. Now we need to maximize $${\text{Area}} = yz + \frac{1}{2}z\sqrt {{x^2} - \frac{1}{4}{z^2}} $$ subject to the constraint $${\text{Perimeter}} = 2x + 2y + z = M$$

We define the Lagrangian
$$L = yz + \frac{1}{2}z\sqrt {{x^2} - \frac{1}{4}{z^2}}  + \lambda (2x + 2y + z - M)$$
We get the following system
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\frac{{xz}}{{\sqrt {4{x^2} - {z^2}} }} + 2\lambda  = 0\\
z + 2\lambda  = 0\\
\frac{{2{x^2} - {z^2}}}{{2\sqrt {4{x^2} - {z^2}} }} + y + \lambda  = 0\\
2x + 2y + z = M
\end{array} \right. \Leftrightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
x = \frac{1}{3}\left( {2\sqrt 3 M - 3M} \right)\\
y = \frac{1}{6}\left( {3 - \sqrt 3 } \right)M\\
z = \left( {2 - \sqrt 3 } \right)M
\end{array} \right.$$

Is this the correct result?